# c# allow user to input again until correct

Tags: c#

I am making an ATM in c#. One of its functions is letting a user transfer money between their accounts. How can I make it so that if the user enters an invalid amount to transfer (such as a negative amount), the user will be prompted to enter an amount again until it is valid? I tried using a while loop but as soon as I entered a negative value line "Please enter a valid amount to transfer" just kept repeating nonstop.

```
Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to transfer?");
                double transferamt = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (transferamt < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount to transfer");

                }
```

Comment: Presumably not a real atm....(please let it be  real ATM!) :)

Comment: This is about as basic as programming gets. I would suggest the OP runs through some of the free online tutorials...

Comment: Of course in a sane world you wouldn't let them press the minus symbol in the first place......When was the last time you used an ATM and it let you enter a negative amount?

Answer (score 10):

Use `double.TryParse`. This ensure no exeption is thrown if the user enters an invalid format. Wrap this in a loop based on the success of the parse.

```
bool valid = false;
double amount;

while (!valid) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to transfer?");

    valid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount);
}
```

You will need to add additional validation for negative values:

```
bool valid = false;
double amount;

while (!valid) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to transfer?");

    valid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount)
        && amount > 0;
}
```

C# processes only the parts of an expression that are required to determine the output. So in the example above, if `double.TryParse(...)` returns false, `amount > 0` will not be evaluated because `false && anything == false`.

`double.Parse` will throw an exception if the value is not a valid double. If `double.TryParse` is not available in your version of .NET you can write your own like so:

```
public bool TryParse(string value, out double output)
{
    output = 0;

    try
    {
        double = double.Parse(value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want a different message for the following attempts, you can rewrite it slightly to:

```
double amount;

Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to transfer?");
bool valid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount)
    && amount > 0;

while (!valid) 
{        
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount to transfer?");
    valid = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount)
        && amount > 0;
}
```

This can be refactored to:

```
void Main()
{
    double amount = GetAmount();
}
double GetAmount()
{
    double amount = 0;
    bool valid = TryGetAmount("How much would you like to transfer?", out amount);

    while (!valid) 
    {        
        valid = TryGetAmount("Please enter a valid amount to transfer?", out amount);
    }

    return amount;
}
bool TryGetAmount(string message, out double amount)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount)
        && amount > 0;
}
```

Comment: `do/while` would be a better refactoring , then you don't need to copy the `bool valid`, which I also think is a compiler error

Comment: @Sayse "Better refactoring" is your opinion. My opinion of `do, while` is quite low simply because it's not used as often as `while` so less is less "comfortable". Besides, using a `do, while` won't allow the custom message. To allow alternate messages in a do while, you'd be talking the same amount of code (and probably compiled to the same IL) so no benefit.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the custom message, As you said its an opinion.. I still believe it is a compiler error though (A local variable named 'valid' is already defined in this scope
)

Comment: @Sayse Good spot on the repeated declaration. A copy paste job! This code is not tested, it's freehand. I'm simply offering alternate solutions, there may be a few minor syntax issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a while loop, but prompt for reading again.

```
while(transferamt < 0){
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount to transfer");
    transferamt = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: This only works if the user enters a valid positive or negative double (or zero). Any other input will result in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `if` which is a *one-time* condition, if you want to keep repeating it until condition is correct then you need to use loop e.g. `while`:

```
double transferamt = -1;
while (transferamt < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount to transfer");
    transferamt = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: This only works if the user enters a valid positive or negative double (or zero). Any other input will result in an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
double transferamt=0;
do{
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid amount to transfer");
transferamt=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

}while(transferamt<0)
```

Comment: There's a serious lack of validation on these posts. Do we all understand the risk of using `double.Parse`? Is nobody considering invalid input (i.e. non-double) other than that specified by the OP (negative values)?!