# Why is the following array not writing to a file?

Tags: c#

I don't understand why the output file does not contain any text?
Why is the array not writing to file? I receive no error whilst running it..

```
    Console.Write("Please enter a name for the homework: ");
    hmwk[1].name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Please enter the subject: ");
    hmwk[1].type = Console.ReadLine();

redo:
    Console.Write("Please enter the date the homework was set xx/xx/xx: ");
    string toconvert = Console.ReadLine();
    DateTime temp;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(toconvert, out temp)== false)
    {
        goto redo;
    }

    DateTime converted = DateTime.Parse(toconvert);
    hmwk[1].dateset = converted;

redo2:
    Console.Write("Please enter the date the homework deadline is: ");
    toconvert = Console.ReadLine();
    if (DateTime.TryParse(toconvert, out temp) == false)
    {
        goto redo2;
    }
    converted = DateTime.Parse(toconvert);
    hmwk[1].deadline = converted;
    StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("homework.txt", false);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].name);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].type);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].dateset);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].deadline);

    Console.WriteLine("You have added the homework. Press Enter.");
```

Comment: Linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) shows proper ways to write to file and links to more information on MSDN. As Ksv3n pointed out you are missing `using`. Please also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671774/c-sharp-allow-user-to-input-again-until-correct as using `goto` is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that link, I've heard it is "bad practice" but I have no idea why.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+why+goto+bad+practce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because it's not [flushed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx). You should `Dispose()` StreamWriter  so it will automatically flush the buffered data to the file. Dispose example with `using`:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("homework.txt", false)) 
{
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].name);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].type);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].dateset);
    outfile.WriteLine(hmwk[1].deadline);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.